# react-native Drawer Navigation with Tab Navigation

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to set a top menu and a tab menu in my app. The bottom tabs are working, but the top menu is not displaying. The top menu that I am trying to set is the one we click and the left menu options show.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer
          ref={navigatorRef => {
            NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
          }}
        />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});

const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: TabNavigator
  }
});

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen: MainStackNavigator
  }
});

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Login: { screen: Login },
  Main: { screen: AppDrawerNavigator }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);
```

I'm new with react native, so I am not sure the order to set the navigator options. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put some code as an example with a `MainDrawerNavigator` that contains a `MainTabNavigator`.  The tab navigator contains three stack navigators for this purpose I'll only reference the `HomeScreenNavigator` which is a stack navigator.  By default this will show a stack header inside my Home tab but will not show a drawer icon to open the drawer.  In order to do this you need to put an icon in to toggle the drawer.  I've shown this by accessing the `navigationOptions` in the `HomeScreen` specifically shown:

```
    static navigationOptions = (navData) => {
        return {
            headerLeft: (
                <View style={styles.headerButtonLeft}>
                    <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={DefaultHeaderButton}>
                        <Item title="menu" iconName="ios-menu" onPress={() => {
                            navData.navigation.toggleDrawer()
                        }} />
                    </HeaderButtons>
                </View>
            ),
        }
    }
```

The above will set an a header button on the left of the `HomeScreen` and pressing the `Item` will trigger toggling the drawer open via `navData.navigation.toggleDrawer()`.  Your example would be similar except your outermost navigator would be your switch navigator it seems.

Full code as an example shown below:  (let me know if clarification is needed elsewhere).

HomeScreen example:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { ... }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text>Home!</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }

    static navigationOptions = (navData) => {
        return {
            headerLeft: (
                <View style={styles.headerButtonLeft}>
                    <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={DefaultHeaderButton}>
                        <Item title="menu" iconName="ios-menu" onPress={() => {
                            navData.navigation.toggleDrawer()
                        }} />
                    </HeaderButtons>
                </View>
            ),
        }
    }
}
```

HomeScreenNavigator example:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';

import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import MediaSelectScreen from '../screens/MediaSelectScreen';
import FinalizePostScreen from '../screens/FinalizePostScreen';
import { userInterface } from '../constants/Colors';
import Styles from '../constants/Styles';

const HomeScreenNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: HomeScreen,
    MediaSelect: MediaSelectScreen,
    FinalizePost: FinalizePostScreen
}, {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: userInterface.accentColor,
            height: Styles.HEADER_HEIGHT,  
        },
    }
});

export default HomeScreenNavigator;
```

MainTabNavigator example:

```
import {  createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import  MessagesScreen  from '../screens/MessagesScreen';
import HomeScreenNavigator from './HomeScreenNavigator';
import LearnScreenNavigator from './LearnScreenNavigator';

const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    LearnScreen: { screen: LearnScreenNavigator, navigationOptions: () =>  ({
        tabBarLabel: 'Learn'
    })},
    HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreenNavigator, navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Home' 
    }},
    MessagesScreen: { screen: MessagesScreen, navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Messages'    
    }},  
});

export default MainTabNavigator;
```

MainDrawerNavigator example:

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';

const MainDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    DrawerNav: MainTabNavigator
}, {
    drawerType: 'slide'
});

export default createAppContainer(MainDrawerNavigator);
```

App.js example:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import AppSwitchNavigator from './navigation/AppSwitchNavigator';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = { ... }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppSwitchNavigator/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ ... });
```